# Dialogflow-es support in session path analytics

Tags: dialogflow-es

just had one questions, i'm currently doing a review on one of my dialogflow-es agent. When i jumped into the analytics view on session path to see which intents are the most interesting and gotten high volume request, i saw this dot "..." symbol that i didn't know what it means, can you guys give some light about this situation to help me review my agents performance better(?), thank you very much.[the image contains the "..." symbol on session path analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aP8EU.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it may be the condensation of several other intents that your agent have, since this session path only show most frequent paths and may have limited space to plot. But I would send them an issue through "Support" section on left bar inside the Dialogflow ES Console. I've sent some doubts in the past few weeks and they answered them.

Comment: yes, it works for me to by sending my issues to dialogflow support team, thank you for answering.